# JCarouselLite seems to scroll only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opencart, jcarousellite

I am terribly new to Javascript/JQuery, so please bear with me if this is a silly question. I have tried to implement JCarouselLite on my site which runs on an Opencart platform with the Oxy theme.

I have finally managed to get my carousel to actually scroll, but the funny thing is, it only scrolls once, and that's it. You'll see what I mean from the website here:-
http://tinyurl.com/qy4ztyn

**This is what I have in my code:-**

```
<div class="image-additional-left">
    <button class="prev">&laquo;</button>
    <button class="next">&raquo;</button>
    <div class="carousel94">
        <ul>
        <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox" rel="colorbox">
            <img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" width="120" height="120" "title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>    
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $(function() {
        $(".carousel94").jCarouselLite({
            vertical: true,
            visible: 4,
            scroll: 1,
            btnNext: ".next",
            btnPrev: ".prev"
        });
    });
//--></script>
```

Am I missing something here? Any advice would be greatly appreciated... Thank you!

Comment: A note: The HTML comment around the Javascript has not been needed for decades! That was something introduced for the benefit of the very first webbrowsers ever and has loooong been obsolete. Also see [_Mozilla MDN: Obsolete practices to avoid_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Obsolete_things_to_avoid#HTML_comments_in_scripts)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've removed the html comment. It didn't help to solve the problem though... :(

Answer (score 1):

I worked with the developer, and managed to resolve the issue. It was due to an old version of jquery that I was using that was not compatible with the plugin.

To resolve the issue, simply use at least a version 1.8 of jquery. :)

Comment: Thanks for the info